# Redux Toolkit: createAsyncThunk action dispatched and return rejected promise the action returns empty payload

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-thunk, redux-toolkit

There is action created using createAsyncThunk and this method return a promise which is handled like this

```
export const action = createAsyncThunk(
  '/fullfilment/update-content-preference',
  async (data, { getState }, thunkAPI) => {
    try {
      const state = getState();
      const authToken = state.auth.token;
      const { selectedShipmentId: shipmentId } = state.fullfilment;
      const obj = {
        ...data,
        shipmentId
      };
      const response = await axios.post(
        '/fullfilment/update-content-preference',
        obj,
        { headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${authToken}` } }
      );
      return response;
    } catch (err) {
      if (err.response) {
        return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue({
          err: err.response,
          status: err.response.status
        });
      }
      return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue({
        err: 'Network Error'
      });
    }
  }
);
```

and below are the promises are handled

```
[action.pending]: state => ({
    ...state,
    loading: true
  }),

  [action.fulfilled]: (state, action) => ({
    ...state,
    data: {
      ...state.data,
      loading: false,
      list: action.payload.data.list
      message: action.payload.data.message
    }
  }),

  [action.rejected]: (state, action) => ({
    ...state,
    loading: false
    error: action.payload.data.error
    message: action.payload.data.message
  })
```

pending resolved and rejected all working well but in rejected i am unable to fetch the data but where action is dispatching thunkApi with error i am getting data there why not in rejected promise. any help would be appreciated thanks

Answer (score 1):

You pass `err` to `rejected` but you forgot use it.

```
error: action.payload.err.data.error
message: action.payload.err.data.message
```

And you are declare `thunkAPI` wrong way. Just update like this:

```
async (data, thunkAPI) => {
  const { getState } = thunkAPI;
}
```

Comment: actually i console the action and am getting payload value to undefine

Comment: action : { payload: undefined , ...restproperties};

Comment: Thank you it resolved my issue.